# best way to overwrite a extension template

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.6.x

what is the best way to overwrite the standard template of typo3 extensions so that they are save for updates?

thanks

Tried this:

```
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
                templateRootPath = fileadmin/webdesign/templates/news/Templates/
                partialRootPath = fileadmin/webdesign/templates/news/Partials/
                layoutRootPath = fileadmin/webdesign/templates/news/Layouts/
        }
}
```

But nothing has changed

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is an example from the tx_news doc:

The TypoScript Setup syntax looks like this:

```
plugin.tx_news {
        view {
                templateRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Templates/
                        1 = EXT:fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Templates/
                }
                partialRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Partials/
                        1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Partials/
                }
                layoutRootPaths {
                        0 = EXT:news/Resources/Private/Layouts/
                        1 = fileadmin/templates/ext/news/Layouts/
                }
        }
}
```

Doc tx_news:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/news/3.0.0/Main/Templating/Start/Index.html

typo3 Doc:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/fluid_styled_content/7.6/Configuration/OverridingFluidTemplates/Index.html

Here another example from slickcarousel:

https://gist.github.com/misterboe/5de7498e810ebd57f7bfb4d2a7abeb66

Comment: I've added the code above but nothing has changed ... ?

Comment: do you want to override tx_news?

Comment: you had to use "templateRootPaths" > S

Comment: the code above is copied from the tx_news manual ... just changed the path that it fits to my path constellation

Comment: have you add it to constants or setup?

Comment: I've added it to constants of the root page

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124627/discussion-between-bschauer-and-felix).

Comment: I tried to do this with sf_banners as well   ´plugin.tx_sfbanners´ but is not working

Answer (score 2):

**Important to Know:**
in TYPO3 CMS 6.2 and before you can just Overwrite the settings

```
templateRootPath  = /path/to/you/template
```

in TYPO3 CMS 7.6  and later you can crate an Array where Fluid / TYPO3 is looking for the template. The Naming is different (now ends with an "s" ) and it must be an Array.

So OLD Examples for Version 6.x will not work in 7.6!

```
templateRootPaths {
    0 = /path/to/originalExtension/template
    1 = /path/to/you/template
}
```

same for partialRootPath -> now partialRootPaths and also layoutRootPath -> now layoutRootPaths

The advantage of this new Array: if you only want to overwrite ONE Partial or one Template: create the Directory in your own extension or Fileadin Folder and just put this one, changed File there

-> the filename should still be Identically
-> Look for CamelCase Errors (f.e. folder Name should be "Layouts" and not "layouts" .. this may work in windows Test System but not on production with linux .. 
-> clear the TYPO3 cache .. as always ..